# How to get iso_date ( YYYYMMDD ) from time_t / timeval

Tags: c, datetime, boost, unix-timestamp

Given a `time_t` as `1291121400`, how do I get the date of that day formatted as `20101130`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me :

```
int iso_date_from_time_t ( const time_t & in_time_t_ ) 
{
     tm temp_this_tm_;

     { // the following to set local dst fields of struct tm ?
         time_t tvsec_ = time(NULL);
         localtime_r ( & tvsec_, & temp_this_tm_ ) ;
     }
     localtime_r ( & in_time_t, & temp_this_tm_ ) ;

     return ( ( ( ( 1900 + temp_this_tm_.tm_year ) * 100 + ( 1 + temp_this_tm_.tm_mon ) ) * 100 ) + temp_this_tm_.tm_mday ) ;
}
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: It might compile, but it didn't give you the answer that is required.  The year is stored '- 1900'; the month is 0-based.  You've not compensated for either of those quirks.  You've also zeroed out the time fields, but that is irrelevant since you don't use them.

Comment: The leading and trailing underscores are ugly, and border-line stepping outside the domain of names reserved to the user; I would not use such names, and would not allow such names to be added to a system where I was code reviewing.  It is not clear why you have the two calls to `localtime_r`, either; the second is sufficient.  That's 7 redundant non-blank lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Somehow the answer seemed right the way I tested it the first time. But obviously the answer was incorrect. Made the suggestions as you suggested and tested them. Seems perfect so far. I try to do localtime_r twice to set dst fields. What I want to achieve is regardless of what today's date is if the input time_t corresponds to a date on which dst was in effect in the local time zone then the answer should be aware of that ?

Comment: One of the reasons that the times switch at 02:00 rather than midnight is that it guarantees that the time falls on the same date (and stays clear of ambiguity as far as possible).  I suspect there are countries (time zones) where the switch is at midnight, in which case, you get odd edge effects; however, those are in a (tiny) minority.  Moreover, because the second `localtime_r()` should overwrite everything in the result structure, I don't see how the first `localtime_r()` can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `gmtime(3)` or `localtime(3)` to convert it into a `struct tm`
(Or, better, the reentrant versions `gmtime_r` or `localtime_r`), and
then use `strftime(3)` to turn it into a string. For example, if you
want the output in UTC:

```
struct tm tm;
char buf[9];
gmtime_r(&my_time_t, &tm);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y%m%d", tm);
printf("The date is: %s\n", buf);
```

Comment: I trust you'll work on the Y10K buffer overflow bug between now and, oh, let's say 9000-01-01?

Comment: Well, strftime takes the buffer size, so it'll truncate the result instead of overflowing the buffer, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `gmtime` or `localtime` and `strftime` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
void function () 
{
    time_t     current_time;
    struct tm *struct_time;

    time( &current_time);

    struct_time = gmtime( &current_time);

    /* Now, you can get the ISO date by 
     * YYYY 'struct_time->tm_year+1900' 
     * MM 'struct_time->tm_mon+1'
     * DD 'struct_time->tm_mday' */
}
```

Please look inside 'struct tm' structure.